# Get NSCFDictionary sub key values

Tags: objective-c, json, serialization, jsonserializer

I am parsing JSON data and I get  a JSON tree like

> 2015-10-13 15:29:10.563 JsonProject[29154:1434114] requestReply: (
>           {
>           DNumb = 512421421;
>           DTempData = "";
>           DUUID = 12;
>           Id = 1;
>       },
>           {
>           DTempData = "";
>           Id = 2;
>       },

As you can see here [sub key values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyte0.png), I got values under `NSCFDictionary` data, but i don't know how to parse them.  I am new on objective-c and came from .net, is there way to parse these values?

Comment: Please, don't post information crucial to getting answer in external links.

Answer (score 0):

Following is your reponse ;

```
equestReply: ( 
    { 
      DNumb = 512421421; DTempData = ""; DUUID = 12; Id = 1;
     },
     { DTempData = ""; Id = 2; 
    })
```

So you can get values as follows ;

```
NSMutableArray* dict = [yourResponseObject  ObjectForKey:"equestReply"];
NSString* = [[dict objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:"DNumb"];
NSString* = [[dict objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:"DTempData"];
NSString* = [[dict objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:"DUUID"];
```

Comment: No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'objectAtIndex:valueForKey:' what is this?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert your JSON data into an `NSArray`:

```
NSError *jsonError;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&jsonError];
```

then you can access each value using its key like this:

```
NSDictionary *jsonItemDic = jsonArray[0];
NSString *dTempData = [jsonItemDic objectForkey@"DTempData"];
```

P.S.: The sample data you have sent is incomplete, it seems though that your JSON is an Array of dictionaries. My Answer relies on this theory.

### Update:

From the screenshots I have seen, you data is stored inside a root dictionary. That means your object's root is a dictionary with a key called `GetVerifiedDevices` and the value of an array of dictionaries. You can access the devices array like this:

```
NSArray *devices = [your_json_object objectForKey:@"GetVerifiedDevices"];
```

and then query your devices like this:

```
for(NSDictionary *deviceDic in devices){
  NSString *dTempData = [deviceDic objectForkey@"DTempData"]; 
//And others like above
}
```

Cheers. M.

Comment: get array but after that i get something like that http://s22.postimg.org/xb86u0j7l/Screen_Shot_2015_10_13_at_16_27_57.png, how can i parse key value?

Comment: and under this data is : http://s16.postimg.org/5q1rjuj85/Screen_Shot_2015_10_13_at_15_30_03.png

Comment: OK, I have seen your Object, it's an array of dictionaries. you see, `NSCFDictionary` is nothing other than the actual `NSDictionary` (CF stands for CoreFoundation) all you have to do is find the dictionary you want and get the value you desire. I'm going to edit my answer.